# SMD vs. THT Difference

Tags: circuit-design, surface-mount, through-hole

I want to know the difference between surface mount device and through hole components other than the mounting style.

Differences such as if the through hole counterpart of the surface mount device has has considerably more resistance or consumes more power etc.

Finally, I want to know if the SMD components can be totally replaced by through-hole in a circuit.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, SMD consumes less board space, is cheaper, has a wider device selection, and has lower pin inductance. There are exceptions to all of these.

Comment: This is very broad, I suggest that you pick a specific product example like an SMPS and limit the question to that context. Power and resistance generally aren't an issue, **cost** and **form factor** are.

Comment: Many devices exist in an smd and tht version and they often include the exact same die in different packages.

Comment: I'm trying to make a board for a microcontroller. THT components will exponentially simplify the soldering process. Ease of soldering is all I'm looking for.

Comment: Some devices are only available as SMD. This can be because the pin density is too high for THT (many MCUs). Or, the because the manufacturer has decided that they won't sell enough THT parts to justify making them.

Comment: If you can get the parts and prefer through-hole, then go ahead; but these days I would say that it doesn't actually simplify soldering at all. You have to keep turning the board over.

Comment: In general on old designs yes. In new designs like PC Cards, NO. So it depends if you want do old school stuff for learning or real work.

Comment: SMD is the present and the future. THT is the past. For manual assembly, THT is easier.

Comment: For larger package sizes (1206), SMD is not really any more difficult than THT. For 0603 and below where a stereo microscope becomes useful it is much more expensive, but you don't need to go that tiny. For bigger stuff you just need a few dollar chisel tip for iron and some fine gauge solder. Consider learning, everything is SMD and there are great tutorials online.

Comment: For manual prototyping assembly, I always use SMD passive components (resistors, capacitors, mosfets, LEDs etc) because the space loss with their THT equivalent is insane even on a proto board.  For the ic's I use THT when available because they fit on perforated boards while the SMD version don't. But if large SMD package with 1.27mm pitch are available then it's even easier than or equally easy as THT packages. With 0.95 mm and 0.63mm pitch it's start to be more difficult, The problem with THT packages with many pins is that it's difficult to insert all the pins into the perforated board.

Comment: Assembly house cost could be more with THT as they need to be hand soldered by most houses

Answer (score 4):

SMD pros: smaller size, can be assembled by pick-and-place machine, no lead inductance or smaller inductance for packages containing leads.

Through-Hole pros: bigger package - better power dissipation (e.g. resistors). Although it depends on PCB design. If SMD component is mounted on copper plane it may have better thermal drain as mentioned in comments below.

Regarding cost - SMD mostly cheaper.

Replacing SMD with through-hole component is not always possible. For example in RF circuits, where lead inductance plays significant role.

Comment: SMD’s may have lower Rjc when surface mounted onto a ground plane than THT with no heat sink at 1/4 the size, so better power dissipation for THT is mot always the case(pun intended) given the same PCB surface area for SMT’s they will be much cooler, but at max case sizes possible TO3’s win.    the biggest difference is all modern MOSFETS are avail with 50k varieties in SMT, vs hundreds in THT especially in low threshold where there are very few %THT of choices. And many VLSI, magnetic, etc , same deal.

Comment: What Tony said. It's impossible to make a blanket claim that through-hole has better power dissipation. Even if they have more surface area, the device body is often hanging in the air, compared to an SMD that could be sitting right on a copper ground plane.

Comment: Gotta say though that is' way easier to heatsink a TO-220 than a D2Pak

Answer (score 1):

SMT’s are cheaper, faster <1ns , better heat transfer to PCB ground plane, cheaper and have 10x more varieties and choices.  For high volume SMD is cheaper production cost and there may be fewer companies with THT automation.

But for old school designs before the turn of century OK.

Comment: Also hobbyist kits for hand soldering

Comment: yet Hobbyists have learned to reflow SMT solder with a hot plate and heat gun or other means